# How to query more than one field using ContentSearch API in sitecore

Tags: c#, lucene, sitecore, sitecore7

I'm working on the Sitecore ContentSearch API.I have indexed a set of fields in an Item.is it possible to query more than one fields at the same time?

```
 public static List<MovieSearchResultItem> SearchResults(string txtQuery)
        {
            using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(indexName).CreateSearchContext())
            {
                var query = context.GetQueryable<MovieSearchResultItem>().Where(result => result.Body.Contains(txtQuery)).ToList();
                return query;
            }
        }
```

In the above query I'm just using the Body field.how to include more than one fields.My search  data might be title or body or someother field so i want to check all three fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add another condition to the `Where` clause:

```
var query = context.GetQueryable<MovieSearchResultItem>()
    .Where(result => result.Body.Contains(txtQuery)
        || result.Title.Contains(txtQuery)
        || result.OtherField.Contains(txtQuery)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple enough, you can add it expression like so:

```
var query = context.GetQueryable<MovieSearchResultItem>().Where(result => result.Body.Contains(txtQuery) || result.Title.Contains(txtQuery))
```

Or you can use the PredicateBuilder, more info on that right here:
  http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/Sitecore-7-Development-Team/Posts/2013/05/Sitecore-7-Predicate-Builder.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend the PredicateBuilder. Example:

```
        Expression<Func<SearchResultItem, bool>> predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<SearchResultItem>();

        predicate = predicate.And(p => p.TemplateName.Equals("News"));
        predicate = predicate.And(p => p.Language == Context.Language.Name);

        List<SearchResultItem> results = context
            .GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
            .Where(predicate)
            .ToList();
```